# React Native: Else in a for loop is not working, the loop skips the first condition and defaults to using the else in the loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, for-loop, conditional-statements

In the code below I have a for loop which goes through a json array, and then pushes data to a new array to be used. The problem is that the loop seems to be using the else and completely skipping the first condition no matter what. This is odd behavior, and I dont know where the error/bug is.

```
const findCompaniesByCategory = async (category) => {
  setCat(category)
var zip = await AsyncStorage.getItem('locationZip')
var newCompanies = []
for(var i in companies){
  if(companies[i].category == category && companies[i].zip == zip){
    
    await newCompanies.push(companies[i])
    await setSuggestions(false)
    await  setUsers(newCompanies)
    await setHide(false)
    setNoResults(false)
    await setCompaniesView(true) 
  }else if(companies[i].category != category){
    await setHide(false)
    setCompaniesView(false)
    setNoResults(true)
  }
}
}
```

Comment: you seem to be `await`ing a lot of things unnecessarily, but I doubt they're the cause of your issue. If the `if` is being skipped when you don't expect it to be, the condition must be false, but without knowing what `companies`, `category` or `zip` are we can hardly help you debug it!

Comment: @RobinZigmond when I don't have an else statement, it works, when I do, it doesn't work.

Comment: define "doesn't work" then. Your original post implies that the code is going into the `else` rather than the `if` as you expect - but there is *no way* that can be caused by simply adding the `else` clause and nothing else. (Other than the obvious fact that without the `else` clause then no code will be executed when the `if` condition fails.) If something strange is happening you need to give a lot more detail to allow others to debug it for you.

Comment: @RobinZigmond the code is going into the else block no matter what when its present. if its not present then the if statement is used but i cant add any other logic besides the one if statement.

Comment: as I said, that's impossible